# Left-Column block replace not working in magento

Tags: magento, themes, customization

I'am trying to replace a content on my left column (layout: **2columns-left.phtml**). It is showing a callout block and a newsletter block (just as the **base/default** template does) but I want to remove both and replace them with a wordpress integration.

My problem is that no metter what I do, the original blocks do not desapear from the left-column. I have followed instructions I found here in Stackoverflow, about editing **catalog.xml** and **newsletter.xml**, finding the block code inside this file and removing it. Didnt work out. Than, understandig that it might being called from the default template, I tried to edit **catalog.xml** and **newsletter.xml** in there too. But nothing happened again.

Today, I have started all over again. This time, I deleted my own template and began customizing the **base/default** template, convicted that this measures would work without the interference of files from others templates. But my problem has more conviction than me.

Does anyone knows something about it that would help me?

Comment: Rohit, you mean Blocks HTML Output, right? This one is disabled.

Comment: Enable template path hint to figure out which blocks are rendered in current page .Check this link http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento

Comment: I've done it already. With that, I can track the blocks phtml files. Than I can delete all the code inside it and the block does desapear, but it still being called to be rendered. But, you know, this is kind of 'sweep the dirt under the rug'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file local.xml in your theme layout folder and add the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<default>
<remove name="left.newsletter"/>
<remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Rohit, thanks for the help, but it also didnt work. Looking to this code I think "that's it, now it will work", but... Here is what I'm going to do: the project I'm developing with magento still in studies period, than, I'll delete all the magento folder I have and I will reinstall a new one, starting from zero again. Than, I'll try your solution. If it work out, good!, otherwise, I came here and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the problem persist even after I've reinstalled all magento framework. I'm not even being able to config (using local.xml) the blocks of the defaut layout that magento's came set with. Do you think that the fact that I'm using magento in Localhost is what is causing this problems? I'm starting to think that it is some preset of the backend. Does something comes to your mind?

Comment: Now I'm doing it! I also need to be constantly flushing the Cashe, but the local.xml is making the blocks disapear! :)